# Make an image overlay the div in a responsive way

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning css and bootstrap and doing some tests. 
I hope to make half of the image overlay on the top of the white text div and in a responsive way, but failed. The div was always below the image. If I set the div z-index to 200, then the div color becomes same as background color. What can I do?
Thanks

```css
.bodyClass {
  background: #ffbc00
}
.container {
  background: #fff
}
.img-overlap {
  margin-left: 150px;
  z-index: 500
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Service</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/myStyle.css">
</head>
<body class="bodyClass">
  <p style="padding:50px 0px 0px 0"></p>
  <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle img-overlap">
  <div class="container">
    Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Try a negative `margin-top`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your target browser(s) are, or what other limitations you have but you could do it like this with absolute positioning & calc().  Actually, if you don't care about centering the image to the text, then you don't even need the calc();

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0 0 25px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <p>
    Arrived compass prepare an on as. Reasonable particular on my it in sympathize. Size now easy eat hand how. Unwilling he departure elsewhere dejection at. Heart large seems may purse means few blind. Exquisite newspaper attending on certainty oh suspicion
    of. He less do quit evil is. Add matter family active mutual put wishes happen.
  </p>
  <p>
    Of recommend residence education be on difficult repulsive offending. Judge views had mirth table seems great him for her. Alone all happy asked begin fully stand own get. Excuse ye seeing result of we. See scale dried songs old may not. Promotion did
    disposing you household any instantly. Hills we do under times at first short an.
  </p>
  <p>
    Advice me cousin an spring of needed. Tell use paid law ever yet new. Meant to learn of vexed if style allow he there. Tiled man stand tears ten joy there terms any widen. Procuring continued suspicion its ten. Pursuit brother are had fifteen distant
    has. Early had add equal china quiet visit. Appear an manner as no limits either praise in. In in written on charmed justice is amiable farther besides. Law insensible middletons unsatiable for apartments boy delightful unreserved.
  </p>
  <p>
    Carriage quitting securing be appetite it declared. High eyes kept so busy feel call in. Would day nor ask walls known. But preserved advantage are but and certainty earnestly enjoyment. Passage weather as up am exposed. And natural related man subject.
    Eagerness get situation his was delighted.
  </p>
  <p>
    Carried nothing on am warrant towards. Polite in of in oh needed itself silent course. Assistance travelling so especially do prosperous appearance mr no celebrated. Wanted easily in my called formed suffer. Songs hoped sense as taken ye mirth at. Believe
    fat how six drawing pursuit minutes far. Same do seen head am part it dear open to. Whatever may scarcely judgment had.
  </p>

  <img src="http://makemomentum.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/puking-rainbow-square.jpg" />

</div>
```

A true CSS ninja will likely have a better way, but from my understanding you either need to get it out of the normal document flow with something like absolute positioning, or you could try using a negative margin

Answer (score 0):

```
z-index
```

works only when the position is absolute or relative.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position: absolute;` under `img-overlap` class. then set `z-index: 10;`.

```css
.bodyClass {
 background: #ffbc00
}
.container {
 background: #fff
}
.img-overlap {
    margin-left: 200px;
 z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Service</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/myStyle.css">
</head>
<body class="bodyClass">
 <p style="padding:50px 0px 0px 0"></p>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsSlzi6GEickw2Ft62IdJTfXWsDFrOIbwXhzddXXt4FvsbNGhp" class="img-responsive img-circle img-overlap">
 <div class="container">
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```